# sudoers - Can I create 3 files with same priority but different names?

Tags: sudo, configuration

I want to create a couple users sudoers file. So I was wondering if the following way is fine?

```
ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/

10_user1
10_user2
10_user3
```

OR should I be incrementing the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple files in `/etc/some_service.d` directories are usually processed in lexicographical order, so that the system administrator can give priority via the file name in order to override default settings made by automatically installed configuration files. This is the origin of the naming convention to start the filenames with a two-digit number.

That means that you can create the files with the same leading number, but they will still be processed in lexicograpical sort order (i.e. first `10_user1`, then `10_user2`, and then `10_user3`). It will not matter unless you have conflicting settings in these three files - which I assume you don't, because you wrote all of them yourself, and therefore probably in a consistent, non-conflicting way.

Answer (score 0):

The files will give out whatever rights to whatever users that you have specified in the files in the order that they are named. In your case `10_user3`, will be processed last.

It really doesn't matter what they are called as long as you don't have one thing for a user in one file and then another thing for the same user in a different file because it will give the rights from the last file that's read and cause conflicts in general. If the files contain rights for those three specific users and nothing else, then you can call them red, green, and blue and it won't make a difference.